# How to create a new array by combining every element of the 1st with every 2nd?

Tags: python, numpy

Need a quick solution in Numpy to get an array in C.
The dimensions and number of elements in the arrays are different.

```
A = [ [1, 2 , 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
         ...  ]
B = [ [a, b],
      [c, d],
      [e, f],
       ... ]

C = [ [1, 2, 3, a, b],
      [1, 2, 3, c, d],
      [1, 2, 3, e, f],
      [4, 5, 6, a, b],
      [4, 5, 6, c, d],
      [4, 5, 6, e, f],
               ...  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Example arrays A and B
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
B = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']])

# Repeat each row of A for the number of rows in B
repeated_A = np.repeat(A, B.shape[0], axis=0)

# Tile B for the number of times A has rows
tiled_B = np.tile(B, (A.shape[0], 1))

# Combine repeated_A and tiled_B along the second axis
C = np.hstack((repeated_A, tiled_B))

print(C)
```

Is it acceptable to use `generator`? If it is, maybe something like this will work:

```
rows_A, cols_A = A.shape
rows_B, cols_B = B.shape

def generate_rows():
    for i in range(rows_A):
        for j in range(rows_B):
            yield np.concatenate((A[i], B[j]))

C = np.fromiter(generate_rows(), dtype=object, count=rows_A * rows_B)
```

Comment: I see that this will work, but it will require a huge amount of memory, this method is not suitable for big data. We need something effective. Is there a batch processing method?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

ai,bi = np.mgrid[0:A.shape[0],0:B.shape[0]].reshape(2,-1)
np.c_[A[ai], B[bi]]
array([['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b'],
       ['1', '2', '3', 'c', 'd'],
       ['1', '2', '3', 'e', 'f'],
       ['4', '5', '6', 'a', 'b'],
       ['4', '5', '6', 'c', 'd'],
       ['4', '5', '6', 'e', 'f']], dtype='<U11')
```

---

You could also use `product` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product

np.r_[[np.r_[i] for i in product(A, B)]]
array([['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b'],
       ['1', '2', '3', 'c', 'd'],
       ['1', '2', '3', 'e', 'f'],
       ['4', '5', '6', 'a', 'b'],
       ['4', '5', '6', 'c', 'd'],
       ['4', '5', '6', 'e', 'f']], dtype='<U11')
```

---

Your Data:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
B = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']])
```

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding cant really tell why. Probably for using `itertools` yet OP specified numpy? Though am sure the numpy solution provided should work

Comment: I upvoted for `itertools`